# Change Sound Volume from .net code

Tags: .net, audio, volume

Is there an easy way to set the volume from managed .net code?

Comment: You want to adjust the system volume? Are you actually playing audio from your application - if so, using what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This rather long article shows how: [Controlling sound volume in C#](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic45693.htm)

Answer (score 4):

This does it for my Windows 7:

Download NAudio (http://naudio.codeplex.com/releases/view/79035) and reference the DLL in your project. Than add the following code:

```
        try
        {
            //Instantiate an Enumerator to find audio devices
            NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator MMDE = new NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator();
            //Get all the devices, no matter what condition or status
            NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceCollection DevCol = MMDE.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(NAudio.CoreAudioApi.DataFlow.All, NAudio.CoreAudioApi.DeviceState.All);
            //Loop through all devices
            foreach (NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDevice dev in DevCol)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Set at maximum volume
                    dev.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevel = 0;

                    //Get its audio volume
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Volume of " + dev.FriendlyName + " is " + dev.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevel.ToString());

                    //Mute it
                    dev.AudioEndpointVolume.Mute = true;
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(dev.FriendlyName + " is muted");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Do something with exception when an audio endpoint could not be muted
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(dev.FriendlyName + " could not be muted");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //When something happend that prevent us to iterate through the devices
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Could not enumerate devices due to an excepion: " + ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This code works on my machine to mute the volume.

Answer (score 1):

[This CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/AudioLib.aspx) demonstrates how you fully control the Windows Mixer settings, including the master volume for the system. It seems to wrap most of the horrible Win API stuff, so it's probably the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer:  You have to use interop.

I wrote a library to do all kinds of sound stuff for you, tho:

WinnMM.Net: http://winmm.codeplex.com/

Comment: The library seems fine, but code samples would be really helpful. Could you please add some?